# Set environment variable in Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian

How do I set environment variable in raspberry pi accessible by `os.path.get('foo')` in Rasberry Pi?
So far I have tried `export foo="xyz"` in the terminal from my home directory. While this gives me `xyz` when entered `echo $foo` within the terminal, my python script prints `None`.

Answer (score 2):

`environ` or `getenv()` would be the appropriate way to retrieve your variable in this case.

```
import os

>>> os.environ["foo"]
'xyz'
>>> os.getenv("foo")
'xyz'
```